# Dynamically change key text size android keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to change key text size of my custom keyboard programmatically. I  have implemented `onDraw` method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(25);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    List<android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();

    for(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key key: keys) {
        if(key.label != null){

            String keyLabel = key.label.toString();

                canvas.drawText(keyLabel, key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);

        }

    }
}
```

But I have to label for any key.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Change in xml layout file

```
android:keyTextColor="Your Color Name"
```

Comment: they asked for dynamically. can't figure out how to set this in the corresponding Java